# Given: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B)$ , prove "OR" statements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B)$

Is that true that $A \in P(B)$ or $B\in P(A)$

I uploaded my solution:

**The question is, is that correct?**

[image]

Comment: it is just the union of two power sets, isn't it? anyway, it seems that your proof goes the wrong direction, you assume what you want to prove

Answer (score 1):

No, you're using the "or" in the wrong way. If $x$ is a real number, then $x\geq 0$ or $x\leq 0$, but you cannot assume that both are true because then $x=0$ and there are non-zero real numbers too.

Same here. Either $A\in\mathcal P(B)$ or $B\in\mathcal P(A)$, but not necessarily both.

But it's not just that. You're not reading the question right. You are given that $\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)=\mathcal P(A\cup B)$. You are not given that $A\in\mathcal P(B)$ and $B\in\mathcal P(A)$. You need to show that at least one of those things are true.

The way to approach this is to say, if $A\in\mathcal P(B)$ then we are done; otherwise let us show that $B\in\mathcal P(A)$. Now you have to use the fact that the power set of the union is the union of the power sets to deduce that.

Comment: Excellent explanation. It helped me alot! I just need to see how can I approach the proof with what is given.

Comment: Did I approach the problem correctly with the second picture I uploaded?

Comment: I'm not sure what $(A\subseteq B)\cup (B\subseteq A)$ means. You don't take a union of two propositions.

Comment: I've uploaded another picture.

Comment: Oh, in the end it is $B \subseteq P(A)$ or $A \subseteq P(B)$ which means it can not be proved. right?

Comment: Uploaded a new solution. can u take a look?

Answer (score 1):

The "assumptions" are wrong, or put another way, your proof proves something like the converse. If $A \subsetneq B$, we have $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$ and thus
$$P(A \cup B) = P(B) = P(A) \cup P(B).$$

One way to approach the problem would be to prove the contrapositive, that is,

> If $A \not\in P(B)$ and $B \not\in P(A)$ then $P(A \cup B) \neq P(A) \cup P(B)$.

From our new hypotheses, we know there are elements $a \in A - B$ and $b \in B - A$. What can we say about the sets in each of $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(A) \cup P(B)$ that contain $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say about $P(A\cup B)$ .But, also you can say(I guess) that $P(A)$ contains just what is in$A $and not in $B$, and $P(B)$ you can say that it contains what is in $B$ and not in $A$. and then you can say that their intersection contains $ A\cup B $ I guess.

Comment: What can you say about containment of the set $\{a, b\}$?

Comment: I've edited my post, what do you think about my second picture?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I'm sorry, I don't understand it. Perhaps it would be useful to write your answer out in complete sentences (but, of course, not totally excluding the use of symbols)?

Comment: I've uploaded another picture.

Comment: Oh, in the end it is $B \subseteq P(A)$ or $A \subseteq P(B)$ which means it can not be proved. right?

Comment: Uploaded a new solution. can u take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Ilan, this is still incorrect. Knowing that $C$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ does not tell us that $C$ must be a subset of $A$ or a subset of $B$. (Consider $A={1,2}$ and $B={2,3,4}$, say, with $C={1,4}$.)

I suggest, as I mentioned in the chatroom, that you look at the contrapositive. As you understand, saying $A\in P(B)$ is saying $A\subseteq B$. So suppose *neither* $A\subseteq B$ *nor* $B\subseteq A$ holds. That means that there is an element of $A$, say $a$, that does not belong to $B$, and there is an element of $B$, say $b$, that does not belong to $A$. Can you now use these to show that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)\cup P(B)$ is false?